# Number of roots lying within a close contour

Tags: complex-analysis

I am little bit curious about the following formula $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_A \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}dz=$ number of roots lying within $A$

where $p(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, with $n$ simple roots, none of which lie on a simple close contour $A$.

How can this be derived out of residues theorem?

Lets take $p(z)=z^n+a_1 z^{n-1}+...+a_n\in\mathbb C[z], n\ge 1$ and choose $r$ large s.t $|p(z)|\ge 1$ for $|z|\ge r$, so we have $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}=\frac{n}{z}+$ parts in $\frac{1}{z^v}, v\ge 2$, how can I proceed?

Comment: You don't want to write $p$ as a sum of monomials, but as a product of roots.  Then you want to induct on the number of roots, segregating the roots into the subsets "inside A" and "outside A".  The Cauchy integral formula you cite will only have contributions from the "inside A" roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the hint by [Eric Towers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652778/number-of-roots-lying-within-a-close-contour#comment1374689_652778): write $p(z)=\prod_{k=1}^n (z-z_k)$ where $z_1,\dots,z_n$ are the roots of $p$ (possibly with repetitions due to multiple roots). Then $$p'(z) = \sum_{j=1}^n\prod_{k\ne j }  (z-z_k)$$
hence 
$$\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}  = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{ z-z_j}$$
In this form, the application of the residue theorem is very straightforward.

Comment: Ok, so appliying the Residue Theorem gives me $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_L\frac{1}{z-z_j}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{z_1,...,z_j\in Int L}I(L,z_1,...,z_j)Res(L,z_1...,z_j)=\sum_{j=1}^{n} j=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$?

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote at all. What are those residues with several $z$ values? For every particular $j$, the function $\frac{1}{z-z_j}$ has exactly one pole, located at $z_j$, with residue equal to $1$. It's like integrating $\frac{1}{z-3}$, which I hope you can do.